# Which font is used here?

Tags: writing-identification, typesetting

Could anyone please help me identify the font used in the image below? (The words read 千羽鶴 - or Senbazuru). Thank you very much!

[image: Font]

Comment: It doesn't seem like a font, judging from kerning or glyph face etc. If you want a free brush font, see here. http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2136161327768901401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

行書体 refers to a style of handwriting, or calligraphy font family simulating such handwriting in general. Not the name of one specific font.

You can browse many samples of Japanese 行書体/毛筆体 fonts here:

- [List of 行書体](http://www.fontfactory.jp/font/list/?fontcategory_id=9&fontbrand_id=&fontweight_id=&os_id=&fonttype_id=&str=&preview_str=%E5%8D%83%E7%BE%BD%E9%B6%B4)
- [List of 筆文字](http://www.fontfactory.jp/font/list/?fontcategory_id=17&fontbrand_id=&fontweight_id=&os_id=&fonttype_id=&str=&preview_str=%E5%8D%83%E7%BE%BD%E9%B6%B4)

Unfortunately, none of them exactly matches the image you provided. Are you sure this image is actually rendered from a computer 'font', installed in someone's computer?

Anyway, if you only need a similar font, I think [昭和龍神書体](http://www.fontfactory.jp/font/detail/kswryujin2/) looks quite similar.